# Unknown column in field list from PHP Query but works in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Ok so I have a really weird one here where I am looking to retrieve information from my database but for some reason, I am getting the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'a.rouk' in
>   'field list'

While it does exist in the database.

I have been through everything and cleared caches and all sorts but nothing seems to be working.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT a.id, a.rouk
FROM table_cp a
WHERE a.active = 1
AND a.rouk REGEXP '.*"data-finder";a:[0-9]+:\{[^{}]*i:[0-9]+;s:[0-9]+:"61"[^{}]*\}'
AND (a.credits = '-1' OR a.credits > '0')
```

When I run this in phpMyAdmin, it works perfectly and finds me the 30 rows I need.

EDITED

The PHP code is as follows using the Symfony framework: -

```
$conn = $em->getConnection();

$sql = "
    SELECT a.id, a.rouk
    FROM table_cp a
    WHERE a.active = 1
    AND a.rouk REGEXP '.*"data-finder";a:[0-9]+:\{[^{}]*i:[0-9]+;s:[0-9]+:"61"[^{}]*\}'
    AND (a.credits = '-1' OR a.credits > '0')
";

$query = $conn->prepare($sql);

$execute = $query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Post `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_cp`

Comment: Can you check your schema validate is perfect? Because my be possible you can use different database

Comment: Also show the PHP code as that is where you say your issue is

Comment: Post the table structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. This is just the issue I have.